# Is there already a function to substract different variables in subsequent quarters?

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I have an unbalanced quarterly panel data set with missing values. I want to substract variable `A2` from `A1` in subsequent quarters. Note that I do not want to get differences of A2, but substract DIFFERENT variables from each other. Differences should be calculated separately for every uid. Besides changing years like Q4 1999 and Q1 2000 are meant to be subsequent.

I am really not sure whether i should concatenate my time index here since packages like zoo only take one index. But that's not the problem here. Here is a some example data:

```
structure(list(uid = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), tndx = c(1999.4, 
2000.1, 2000.2, 1999.4, 2000.1, 2000.1, 2000.2, 2000.3), A1 = c(2, 
2, 2, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1), A2 = c(3, 3, 3, 14, 14, 2, 100, 2)), .Names = c("uid", 
"tndx", "A1", "A2"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

# which results in
  uid   tndx A1  A2
1   1 1999.4  2   3
2   1 2000.1  2   3
3   1 2000.2  2   3
4   2 1999.4 10  14
5   2 2000.1 11  14
6   3 2000.1  1   2
7   3 2000.2  1 100
8   3 2000.3  1   2
```

If you prefer a separated index, use this example:

```
# Thx Andrie!
x2 <- data.frame(x, colsplit(x$tndx, "\\.", names=c("year", "qtr")))
```

Is there a good way to solve this with `reshape2`,  `plyr` or even base or would you rather write a custom function?

Note, it is also possible that some `uid` occurs only once. Obviously you can't calculate a lagged difference then. Still I need to check for that and create an NA then.

Comment: @Andrie: Cool, I did not know that you could use diff and head this flexible. Still I have problem when the year switches. I edited my example - please try the new structure with your function - it does not account for a change of year of uid 2. Obviously q1 of 2000 and q4 of 1999 should be subsequent and therefore diff should not be NA.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the observations for each uid will always run in sequence (i.e. there are no missing quarters)

Comment: No unfortunately not, THAT is the problem.

Comment: Please don't comment on answers in your question.  This becomes very confusing.  To illustrate, I have deleted my answer until I have a better understanding of your question.  This means that as your question now stands, it makes no sense.

Comment: What I want to do is: get the difference of A1 and A2 if quarters are subsequent and store NA if not (i.e. one of the values is missing or entire line).

Comment: Ok, I understand about the confusion and realized that you deleted your answer. What do you suggest? How can I correct my question, to make it easier to understand? Rather only by editing? I am serious here – just want to learn how it's properly done.

Comment: Your question is a good one.  Just edit it so it stands by itself (i.e. don't reference any answers)

Comment: Please, please don't refer to answers in your question.  This makes it difficult for future readers to understand what's going on.  By all means, edit your question to reflect issues that crop up in the answers.  However, it should be possible to understand the question by reading the question by itself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4911/discussion-between-ran2-and-andrie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We split it on the `uid` using `by` and within the function that operates on each set of rows for a single `uid`, we create a zoo object, `z`, using `yearqtr` class for the index.  Then we merge the time series with an empty series having all the desired quarters including any missing intermediate quarters giving `zm` and perform the computation giving `zz`.  Finally we convert to the `data.frame` form on the way out:

```
library(zoo)
to.yearqtr <- function(x) as.yearqtr(trunc(x) + (10*(x-trunc(x))-1)/4)

DF <- do.call("rbind", by(x, x$uid, function(x) {
    # columns of x are: uid tndx A1 A2
    z <- zoo(x[c("A1", "A2")], to.yearqtr(x$tndx))
    zm <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/4)))
    zz <- with(zm, cbind(zm, `A1 - A2 lag` = A1 - lag(A2, -1)))
    if (ncol(zz) <= ncol(z)) zz$`A1 - A2 lag` <- NA # append NA if col not added
    data.frame(uid = x[1, 1], tndx = time(zz), coredata(zz), check.names = FALSE)
}))
```

which gives this:

```
> DF
    uid    tndx A1 A2 result A1 - A2 lagged
1.1   1 1999 Q4  2  3     NA             NA
1.2   1 2000 Q1  2  2     NA             -1
1.3   1 2000 Q2  2  3     NA              0
2.1   2 1999 Q4  2  4     NA             NA
2.2   2 2000 Q1 NA NA     NA             NA
2.3   2 2000 Q2 NA NA     NA             NA
2.4   2 2000 Q3 NA NA     NA             NA
2.5   2 2000 Q4 NA NA     NA             NA
2.6   2 2001 Q1  3  4     NA             NA
3.1   3 2000 Q1  1  2     NA             NA
3.2   3 2000 Q2  1 NA     NA             -1
3.3   3 2000 Q3  1  2     NA             NA
```

EDIT: Completely re-did the solution based on further discussion.  Note that this not only adds an extra column but it also converts the index to `"yearqtr"` class and adds the extra missing rows.

EDIT: Some minor simplifications in the `by` function.

Comment: I like the second approach, but still my biggest concern is that I do have missing intermediate quarters. Output-wise I would love to add a column to the original data.frame that contains the difference or NA if the difference cannot be calculated. Thx for making it consisten with the data – sorry i had to edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. Now we're almost there. I made another edit concerning problems with single uids. However, thanks for the big lift, man. I have a work around for that, so I accepted your answer!

Comment: I have added a check for that.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't entirely clear what you wnated because you didn't include a "right answer". If you want to subtract one lagged variable from another unlagged variable you cna do that with indexing that is offset. (You do need to pad the result if you wnat it to get put back into the dataframe.

```
 x$A1lagA2 <- ave(x[, c("A1", "A2")], x$uid, FUN=function(z) {
            with(z, c(NA, A1[2:NROW(z)] -A2[1:(NROW(z)-1)]) ) } )[[1]]
 x
  uid   tndx A1  A2 A1lagA2
1   1 1999.4  2   3      NA
2   1 2000.1  2   3      -1
3   1 2000.2  2   3      -1
4   2 1999.4 10  14      NA
5   2 2000.1 11  14      -3
6   3 2000.1  1   2      NA
7   3 2000.2  1 100      -1
8   3 2000.3  1   2     -99
```

You do get annoying duplicate extra columns with ave() when it argument is multicolumn, but I just took the first one.

Comment: This is slick. But there remains a problem. If line 7 was removed from the dataset A1lagA2 would be -1 but it should be NA. If there is no subsequent quarter the A1lagA2 should become NA.

Comment: From experience, I'm expecting Gabor's solutions to be better in just about every way than mine. If you edit your example to include further "challenges" and post the expected answer, I'm guessing the solutions will be forthcoming.

Comment: At the moment I am working on Gabor's solution with my real dataset and it seems really nice. Still though I like your solution a lot since it is a lot easier because no need for creating all these empty values. Do you have an idea how to check if all quarters of an uid are subsequent?